# How can I get a fixed sidebar?

Tags: html, css, fixed, sidebar

I am using the following code to build a fixed sidebar, which should be always 100 percent height and 20 percent width. The main part should be displayed next to it.

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
main {
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">

  <nav>

    <ul>

      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</div>


<main>

  <div id="content">

    Content

  </div>

</main>
```

The code doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

By fixing the sidebar, you're throwing it out of the usual order of CSS elements. So setting your `main` to `80%` here doesn't really create the `20% + 80%` illusion you're hoping to achieve. Instead, your `main` gets **under** the sidebar, and it's also only `80%` in width.

What you want is a `100%` `main`, with padding of `20%` to the left, so nothing ever gets there, and thus all your content is visible.

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">

  <nav>

    <ul>

      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</div>


<main>

  <div id="content">

    Content

  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
main {
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00F none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  min-height: 1200px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main>
   <div id="content">
    Content
   </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-left: 20%` to `main` to offset the space covered by `#sidebar`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
main {
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<main>
  <div id="content">
    Content
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a left margin to the main div as wide as the sidebar.

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
main {
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 1200px;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">

  <nav>

    <ul>

      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</div>


<main>

  <div id="content">

    Content

  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine however the sidebar is overlapping the main content. What you can do is add position property to the main content and adjust its left property.

Try this code with position property and left property. :)

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
main {
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 1200px;
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">

  <nav>

    <ul>

      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</div>


<main>

  <div id="content">

    Content

  </div>

</main>
```